# Input type="time" more than 24 hours

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I just ran into the following problem:

In a web-app UI I want the user to input a timeframe in hours in which to respond to a message. The timeframe should be up to 72 hours. We’d love to use `<input type="time">` but its limited to 24 hours max.

`<input type="time">` has an optional max value. I think a default maximum of 24 hours makes sense but it would be handy if the max could get set all the way up to 99:99 hours.

Any suggestions on where I can suggest a change in the standard?

Comment: Use `type=number`? Or range?

Comment: To change the standard, you'd want to contribute to [W3](https://www.w3.org/community/html5spec/)

Comment: input type="number" is the form control attribute that you desire. input type="time" is for creating time-stamps

Comment: Isn't 48:00 h a valid time-stamp? type=time is just perfect for this use case: you can type in both hours and minutes together, you can step the hour/minute via the ui-steppers and it has a ui for touch devices. With input type=number I'd have to recreate all those things to have a comparable user experience.

Comment: Did you find solution. I have similar problem with time input. I have tested few timepicker plugins but without sutisfing results. 
I will be grateful for any clue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `number` type as:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: I know about type=number but its user experience would I use two of them for hour:minute would be way behind type=time. To recreate a comparable user experience I'd have to recreate that it jumps back and forth between hour and minute while typing and via the delete/arrow-left/arrow-right etc..

Answer (score -4):

```
<input type="time" name="time">
```

Use this in the form validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('time', 'time','required|max_length[100]');
```

Here the first time is the name in the input field and the second word time is the if we given wrong then it will display the time is wrong and required is the word or the tag used for the specific mention(i.e user should fill the field otherwise it shows that as error) and max length is the maximum length of the field area it is only possible by using the codeignetor by using the php