# input type time with more than 24 hour options

Tags: html, forms, input

I want to use a time input to allow user to select a precise time in a video (on some really long videos).
I don't want the input to limit the selection to max 23:59:59, is it possible to select for eg 46:59:10 ?

ie. keeping to original behavior on minutes and seconds part but allow hours to go past 23 ?

I tried setting `max="10000:00:00"` but that doesn't change the input behavior.

A more general use case would be to allow duration input that may be bigger than 1 day

```html
<label>Select a duration: <input type="time" step="1"/></label>
```

Comment: Can add your current code to your question?

Comment: I added a short snippet to illustrate

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891274/input-type-time-more-than-24-hours

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any easy way except this one, with two `input`s:

```css
/* Standardize the different styles of the inputs */
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<label>Select a duration (days and time):</label><br>
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" /><input type="time" step="1" />
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's a nice track for something bigger maybe. Do you think it's possible to have only minutes and seconds ? So I could set a number fields for hour and time field for minute/seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the best solution I found is to apply a pattern to the input:

```
<input id="inputId" pattern="[0-9]+:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$" placeholder="hh:mm:ss"/>
```